# Why are my table rows not aligning properly?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background, html-table

I'm making my first website and I ran into some problems with tables and the background. Here's a screen pic I took with my phone.If I preview this on my computer screen it look's a bit better because I don't have the background problem but anyway I can't figure out what is wrong with tables (specifically the 4th pic) and is my background not responsive. Btw all the picture are the same size....

[image]

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Projects</title>
            <link href="css2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>
        <head>
            <div class="logo" >
                <img src="lg.png" alt="" width="180" height="178" class="logo"/>
            </div>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>mt</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="About.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="box" >
            <div class="table" >
                <table width="900" height="200" border="0" cellspacing="7" cellpadding="9">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="row" > 
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="project1.html">
                                            <div class="raste">
                                                <img src="logos.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                                <li>
                                    <a href="project2.html">
                                        <div class="raste"> 
                                            <img src="elite.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                                <li>
                                     <a href="project3.html">
                                        <div class="raste"> 
                                            <img src="time.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="project4.html">
                                        <div class="raste">  
                                            <img src="booksrie.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="project5.html">
                                        <div class="raste">
                                            <img src="log.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="project6.html">
                                        <div class="raste">
                                            <img src="log.jpg" alt=""      width="300"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
           </div>
        </body>
 </html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
.logo {
padding-bottom: 0.5%;
text-align: center;
}
nav {
font-family: "Proxima";
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
word-spacing: 80px;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-bottom: 1%;
padding-left: 50px;
color: #000000;
}
li {
display: inline;
color: #000000;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
a:hover {
color: lightgray;
}
a:active {
color: black;
}
body {
background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
table {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
}
.raste img {
height: 190px;
width: 300px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
display: block;
border: none;
border-radius: 10px;    
}
.raste img:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.079);
transform: scale(1.079);
}
.table {
display: table;
margin: 1em auto;
}
.row {
display: table-row;
}
.raste {
display: table-cell;
}
@font-face {
font-family: Proxima;
src: url(Fonts/Proxima_Regular.otf);
}

ul {
padding: 0;
}
.box {
background:#000000;
width: 100%;
background-size: 0% auto;
margin-bottom: 5%;
border-radius: 10px;
padding-bottom: 1%;
padding-top: 1%; 
}
```

Comment: tables are for tabular data - not layout.  Also you seem to have some orphaned `li` tags. but it looks like you are trying to have a 900px table but you have 300px images (x3) plus 9px padding in each cell and 7px between cells = so I'm guessing your cells are overflowing the table by 82px?

Comment: First of all, your html code is full of errors. e.g. two closing body tags, `li` elements in your table without an `ul`,.. create valid html and then you might have something to work with.

Comment: I fixed the the body tags... but i don't understand... what is wrong with the links and size?? can you please be more specific because I'm fairly new at this

Comment: don't use a table, so element can wrap and break into lines. img 300px width + padding ... it surely is difficult to feet on small screens :) . else, display on table elements can be reset too. Any how, it could be wised to use media queries so you can decide when &  how to break the design on different screen size

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap grid example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo2c3L4t/)

HTML

```
<div class="main pull-left">
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 box">1</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 box">2</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 box">3</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 box">4</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 box">5</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 box">6</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{padding:0px; margin:0px;}
.main{width:100%; background:#000; border-radius:10px; padding:10px;}
.main .box{background:#fff; color:#000; border:solid 4px #000; padding:20px 0px; text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up your html deleting all tags useless , so it is easier to style, to maintain and to validate.

example :

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 .logo {
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  font-family: "Proxima";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  word-spacing: 80px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  padding-left: 50px;
  color: #000000;
}
nav:before {
  content: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/6);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav:before,
.table {
  display: table;
  margin: auto; 
  max-width: 1040px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
a:hover {
  color: lightgray;
}
a:active {
  color: black;
}
body {
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
}

.raste img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.raste img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.079);
  transform: scale(1.079);
}
.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  justify-content:center;
}
.raste {
  padding: 15px;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Proxima;
  src: url(Fonts/Proxima_Regular.otf);
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  background: #000000;
  background-size: 0% auto;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<nav> <a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a>  <a href="About.html">ABOUT</a>  <a href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
<div class="table">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="project1.html">
      <div class="raste">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x190/456&text=logo.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="project2.html">
      <div class="raste">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x190/55f&text=elite.jpg" alt="" width="300" />
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="project3.html">
      <div class="raste">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x190/fed&text=time.jpg" alt="" width="300" />
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="project4.html">
      <div class="raste">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x190/bad&text=booksrie.jpg" alt="" width="300" />
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="project5.html">
      <div class="raste">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x190/a55&text=log.jpg" alt="" width="300" />
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="project6.html">
      <div class="raste">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x190/ef0&text=log.jpg" alt="" width="300" />
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still not working properly... the size of the image is 7,12cm x 4 cm... when i palace this iside it made the late two images larger than the rest

Comment: @MaticToni  I did not give any size to image in the snippet cause they are all 190x300 , what about the ones you are using ? what about the html & CSS you are using ? is it the snippet not working or your new attempt ?

Comment: probaly my attempt...i realy don't know what else to do...it only looks ok if the page width is 1000..how can this be?

Comment: @MaticToni try to build a http://codepen.io/pen or a http://jsfiddle.net so we can see your code and problems online :)  i had removed the width:100% on .box, did you ? (i'll be offline a few hours)

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQNYqa/ i coppied all the code and it look's perfect on codepen but in dreamweaver it looks like this http://postimg.org/image/d6gkhads3/ ...

Comment: @MaticToni do not trust 100% dreamweaver, check your pages within a couple of browsers to make sure it does what expected, maybe there is nothing wrong but with dreamweaver.

Comment: checked it online and it makes a even bigger mess than in dw

Comment: is there another way so i can keep the tables?

Comment: @MaticToni table-rows do not break into lines. unless you reset display via mediaqueries to turn 3 col to 2 then 1. else, bootstrap would manage this on its own allwright

Comment: @MaticToni  a quick example with table and display reset via mediaqueries, does dreamweaver can handle this ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPJwGN

Comment: @MaticToni should i update my answer so you can upvote and accept it ?